# How to append all values from a field into an empty list in Python using search cursor

Tags: python, list, cursor, append, arcpy

I am a beginner to Python trying to append all of the values from the YYYYMMDD field to an empty list.

My code looks like this:

```
Date_list = [ ] 

rows = arcpy.da.SearchCursor(path + 'myfile.shp', ['YYYYMMDD'])

for r in rows:
    Date_list.append(r.getValue("YYYYMMDD"))
```

When I run it, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\owner\Documents\Project\work.py", line 102, in <module>
Date_list.append(rows.getValue("YYYYMMDD"))
AttributeError: 'da.SearchCursor' object has no attribute 'getValue'
```

How else could I potentially append all of the date values into my empty list?

Answer (score 3):

Esri introduced the data access (da) module to arcpy at 10.1 (see [DevSummit 2012 proceeding](http://proceedings.esri.com/library/userconf/devsummit12/papers/introducing_the_arcpy_data_access_module.pdf)).  As stated by M4rtini, this provide two SearchCursor classes (i.e. one 'Classic' under arcpy and the other under arcpy.da)

- [arcpy.SearchCursor](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//018v00000050000000): 'Classic' cursors work with row objects - Row values area accessed with setValue/getValue properties
- [arcpy.da.SearchCursor](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//018w00000011000000): arcpy.da cursors use lists and tuples - Row values are accessed by index

For this reason, there two possilbe answers to this question:

1. Remove the **da** class:

   ```
   Date_list = [ ] 

   rows = arcpy.SearchCursor(path + 'myfile.shp', ['YYYYMMDD'])

   for r in rows:
       Date_list.append(r.getValue("YYYYMMDD"))
   ```
2. Access the row value with index reference (as proposed by Sergey):

   ```
   Date_list = [ ] 

   rows = arcpy.da.SearchCursor(path + 'myfile.shp', ['YYYYMMDD'])

   for r in rows:
       Date_list.append(r[0])
   ```

Answer (score 2):

A brief look at the ArcGIS documentation suggests that iterating over a cursor produces plain Python tuples. Tuples do not have `getValue` method in Python.

Try this:

```
for r in rows:
    Date_list.append(r[0])
```

Comment: You can also provide the following link: http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//018w00000011000000

Comment: The confusion of OP probably comes from that there excists two set's of cursors. The one's under arcpy.da is prefered, but the old ones under arcpy does have getValue methods. [source](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//002z0000001q000000)

Answer (score 0):

The "long" way:

```
import arcpy
import os

Date_list = []
path = "C:\SomeFolder"
shp = arcpy.management.MakeFeatureLayer(os.path.join(path, "myfile.shp"))

with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(shp, "YYYYMMDD") as rows:
    for row in rows:
        Date_list.append(row[0])
```

The "short" way:

```
import arcpy
import os

path = "C:\SomeFolder"
shp = arcpy.management.MakeFeatureLayer(os.path.join(path, "myfile.shp"))

Date_list = [row[0] for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(shp, "YYYYMMDD")]
```

Always create a feature layer as it is faster than accessing a file on disk.